# Get relative sized sting between delimiters

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I'm trying to parse a string that could change it's size with the grok filter. 
A fast research around the interned returned no clear information if this is possible.
What I have is:

`SOME STRING THAT IS PARSED "I NEED TO PARSE THIS STRING AND IT CHANGES IT'S SIZE SOMETIMES"`

is there any construction that can return the string in between `" "`?

I suppose there has to be something like this:

`match => { "message" => "%{GET THE STRING BETWEEN}" }`

Comment: Tried `%{QUOTEDSTRING:str}`?

Comment: No, but it worked out. Is there a full documentation of the predefined patterns?What i found so far are only tutorials.

Comment: The patterns are available [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns), with the basics in the grok-patterns file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the **QUOTEDSTRING** (e.g. `%{QUOTEDSTRING:str}`) pattern.

See [more pre-defined Grok patterns here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns).